# Best practice to make SOAP call to long running external web service

Tags: apex, soap-api

It is a good practice I make a SOAP call to an external service salesforce using a custom button (js)?

Many customers need to send sales order to ERP, in a standard page insert a custom button (js) that calls my apex method that performs the call to the ERP, however this time the screen is frozen to the user aguarando the ERP response. What would be the best way to make this call?